# open page to use navigation and token system to show a pdf file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have download one mupdf project for pdfreader and i have some changes.

I am stuck some where when i click on list pdf file then open but it return a null navigation error.

when i am going to another place click on list this is working.my code and fileinfo property is correct but problem in _navigation.

Please Help me...

```
 public void OpenFile(IFileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        if (IsLoading)
            return;

        _navigationService.UriFor<FileViewerPageViewModel>().WithParam(x => x.CurrentFileId, fileInfo.Id).Navigate();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using Caliburn.Micro?

Comment: yes actually i dont know Caliburn.Micro but when i am mouse over on _navigation this word is there

Comment: You don't know? How are you developing it then? Also, the exception message is "Cannot navigate without attaching an `INavigationService.CallAttachTo` first". Have you called that method yet?

Comment: How to call this INavigarionServices to open fileviewerpage

Comment: But if you don't know, why are you using Caliburn.Micro?